# How to select/mask this object from black background

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to crop only the object not the black background.
How can it be done it using python / openCV?

[image]

I have used the following code, I only need object

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# original image
# -1 loads as-is so if it will be 3 or 4 channel as the original
image = cv2.imread('/content/image1.jpg', -1)
# mask defaulting to black for 3-channel and transparent for 4-channel
# (of course replace corners with yours)
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
roi_corners = np.array([[(10,10), (300,300), (10,300)]], dtype=np.int32)
# fill the ROI so it doesn't get wiped out when the mask is applied
channel_count = image.shape[2]  # i.e. 3 or 4 depending on your image
ignore_mask_color = (255,)*channel_count
cv2.fillPoly(mask, roi_corners, ignore_mask_color)
# from Masterfool: use cv2.fillConvexPoly if you know it's convex

# apply the mask
masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)

# save the result
cv2.imwrite('image_masked.png', masked_image)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you clarify in broad terms, or with a mocked up example, how the output should look please?

Comment: the output should only the object as image , which is use to draw multiple objects on a black image

Comment: when I run that no black background removed

Comment: I still don't get it. Let's call the object a meteor, so I assume you just want the meteor - so what will be in your output image where the black currently is?

Comment: yes , just want meteor and the remaining pixels (black will be removed) and paste the object ( two or three time ) on any blank image with different angles

Comment: What will be there where the black was?

Comment: if you don't like either of the two existing answers... that is perhaps because the transparency masks are binary (yes/no). a grayscale transparency channel could be calculated... but that's a little more complicated. one would have to (1) react to the fading black around the object (2) remove the black from the mix of every pixel (or else declare the picture to be "*premultiplied* alpha")

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the next following code. You can play with the minimum threshold value to achieve better results (I found that 50 works great)

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread(PathToYourImageFile)
imageGray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(imageGray, 80, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
b, g, r = cv2.split(image)
rgba = [b, g, r, thresh]
imageResult = cv2.merge(rgba, 4)
cv2.imwrite("ImageResult.png", imageResult)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make the black background transparent as follows.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("0byhS.jpg", 1)
tmp = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,alpha = cv2.threshold(tmp,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
rgba = [b,g,r, alpha]
dst = cv2.merge(rgba,4)
cv2.imwrite("test.png", dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer how can I used this image to generate a image with multiples of these objects at random angle ?

Answer (score 0):

Building on top pf previous solutions.

If you want to show multiple of these at random angles, one problem is going to be of aspect ratio, hence reduction in size.

For this example we are  going to.

- Reducing size of image by 40%
- Copying and rotating it randomly  in the multiples of 60 deg.
- Arranging the rotated images horizontally

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('comet.jpg')
imageGray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(imageGray, 80, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
b, g, r = cv2.split(image)
rgba = [b, g, r, thresh]
imageResult = cv2.merge(rgba, 4)

# code to merge images
(h, w) = imageResult.shape[:2] 
center = (w//2,h//2)
arr = [ i for i in range( 10 , 360, 60)]

all_images = []

for _ in range(len(arr)):
       angle = np.random.choice(arr)
       M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 0.4)
       rotated = cv2.warpAffine(imageResult, M, (w, h))
       all_images.append(rotated)

#merged_images = cv2.vconcat(all_images) #vertical concat
merged_images = cv2.hconcat(all_images) #horizontal concat
cv2.imwrite("comet_merged.png", merged_images)
```

Result:
[image]